# Dynamic URL Django problems

Tags: django, django-models

Im making a journal-program for dental offices, using django. I want to make dynamic URLs for the clinics page and for individual patients aswell.
I want the URLs to inherent the id's of both the clinic and patient.
The models.py:

```
class klinik(models.Model):
klinikid = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class patient(models.Model):
id_nr = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

The views.py:

```
def klinik(request, k_id):
    klinikker = klinikker.objects.get(klinik_id=k_id)
    patients= patient.objects.all()
    return render(request,'DentHelp/klinik.html', {'patients':patients})
    
   def registering(request, fd):
   patientsid = patient.objects.get(id_nr=fd)
   return render(request,'DentHelp/registrering.html')
```

The URLS.py

```
    path('klinik/<str:k_id>/', views.klinik),
    path('registrering/<str:fd>/', views.registering),
```

Something must be right, because the patients page called registrering is loading nicely, however the klinik page says the object hasnt been declared.

Do you see any mistakes?

Comment: why you are using `klinikker.objects.get(klinik_id=k_id)` and then give `patient.objects.all()` to the template?

Comment: I need it for a table on the klinik page

Answer (score 0):

"kliniker" is not the name of your model and "klinik_id" must be "klinikid":

```
klinikker = klinik.objects.get(klinikid=k_id)
```

In any case your code doesn't make any sense. In a function you define "kliniker" but you don't use it and it's useless. You do the same with patient in the other function.

Comment: correct, fixed it, but still didnt work, the klinik object doesnt seem to be reconized like the object, like the patient is.

Comment: Probably your problem is that you are not passing it to the template: return render(request,'DentHelp/klinik.html', {'patients':patients, 'klinikker':klinikker''})